# Memory for a fatal1ty z170 gaming k6 motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

My fatal1ty z170 gaming k6 motherboard has 4 memory slots.  I am using 2 of them with G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Desktop Memory Model F4-3200C16D-16GVKB.

So that leaves me with 2 empty slots.  One of the empty slots can't be used because the CPU fan is in the way.

My question is, does memory still need to be installed in pairs?

So in that one available slot, can I put a 16 MB stick in there, or would it be better to put an 8 MB stick like the other ones that are installed?

Comment: Its best if you load both slots with a matched pair (kit) of modules, as this board likes dual channel memory config.

Comment: There are low profile DDR4 modules that will have no problem fitting under the fan.  You should not attempt to use a single 16 GB you will experience problems with a configuration like that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be installed in pairs? No.
Will it hurt your performance if not installed in pairs? Yes.